# What are the probabilities for the events $A$ and $A\cap B\ $?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, matrices

We have a $16\times 3$-matrix. We randomly choose $24$ places which we fill with ones, the remaining $24$ places are filled with zeros. The number of such matrices is therefore $$\binom{48}{24}$$

The matrix contains $16$ rows.

Now, we have two events :

- A : There is at least one row containing only zeros
- B : There is at least one row containing only ones

> What is the probability of the events $A$ and $A\cap B$ ?

Due to symmetry, we have $P(A)=P(B)$. In a simulation, I got that the probability that neither $A$ nor $B$ occurs, is $0.017$ , the probability that $A$ occurs, but not $B$ is $0.056$. Due to symmetry, the probability that $B$ occurs, but not $A$ , must be the same. And finally, the probability that both $A$ and $B$ occur, is $0.871$

I think the inclusion-exclusion-method should be helpful, but I did not manage to actually calculate the required probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case with "at least one" events, it seems easier to work with the events' complements.  We use a generating function approach, with a computer algebra system to ease the computations.

$A^c$ is the event that all the rows contain at least one zero.  The generating function for the number of ways to place $r$ zeroes in a 16 by 3 matrix with at least one zero in each row is
$$f(x) = \left( \binom{3}{1} x + \binom{3}{2} x^2 + \binom{3}{3}x^3 \right)^{16}$$
The coefficient of $x^{24}$, which is the number of ways to place $24$ zeroes in the matrix with at leaast one zero in each row, is
$[x^{24}]f = 2,348,209,259,370$,
so 
$$\Pr(B^c) =\Pr(A^c) = [x^{24}]f \; / \; \binom{48}{24} \approx 0.0728181$$
and
$$\Pr(B) = \Pr(A) \approx \boxed{0.927182}$$

Continuing, $A^c \cap B^c$ is the event that each row contains at least one zero and at least one one, or equivalently, each row contains one or two zeroes.  This time the generating function is
$$g(x) = \left( \binom{3}{1} x + \binom{3}{2} x^2 \right)^{16}$$
and the coefficient of $x^{24}$, which is the number of ways to place $24$ zeroes in the matrix with one or two zeroes in each row, is $[x^{24}]g = 554,011,299,270$, so
$$\Pr(A^c \cap B^c) = [x^{24}]g \; / \;\binom{48}{24} \approx 0.0171799$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align}
\Pr(A \cap B) &= 1-\Pr((A \cap B)^c) \\
&= 1 - \Pr(A^c \cup B^c) \\
&= 1-[\Pr(A^c) + \Pr(B^c) - \Pr(A^c \cap B^c)] \\
&\approx \boxed{0.871544}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Impressing answer (+1 and accept) !

Comment: This is amazing!